# How to specify usb device path?

Tags: python

I'm trying to access a path on my phone, which is connected on my notebook windows 11, with some documents using this python code, but i'm having difficult to specify the path name on my code.

```
import os
import time
import usb.core

vendor_id = 0x22B8
product_id = 0x2E76

# Localiza o dispositivo USB
device = usb.core.find(idVendor=vendor_id, idProduct=product_id)

# Se o dispositivo não for encontrado, exibe uma mensagem de erro
if device is None:
    raise ValueError('Dispositivo USB não encontrado')

# Configura o dispositivo para uso
device.set_configuration()

print("device address:", device.address)

while True:
    # Caminho para a pasta com os arquivos
    dir_path = "Este Computador\moto g(8) play\Armazenamento interno compartilhado\Documents"

    # Lista todos os arquivos na pasta e remove . e ..
    files = [f for f in os.listdir(dir_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, f))]

    # Ordena os arquivos pela data de modificação
    files.sort(key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(dir_path, x)), reverse=True)

    # Obtém o arquivo mais recente
    latest_file = files[0]

    print("\nArquivo mais recente:", latest_file)

    time.sleep(1)
```

I put the windows path just to illustrate

What's the best way to identify the folder path?

Comment: To start and end a multi-line code block, use a line with _three_ backticks, not a single backtick alone.

Comment: That said, PyUSB doesn't expose a filesystem interface; that's not what it's for, and the difference between what you have and what you want is arguably too broad to fit into a reasonably-scoped question.